# Setup for Hindi/Sanskrit Roman Transliteration with Diacritics?

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, linux, indic, hindi

I am on Linux and am using Ibus and M17n to input Devanagari.

I find that inputting tranliterations does not work as well.

So I have two questions:

1) Is there a good way to get an output of transliteration from Devanagari (Hindi, and Sanskrit) in Latex (or another program)

2) Is there a good way to input tranliteration version of Devanagari, using Ibus (or another method)

My concern, is that I don't want to have to type twice the same material, I would like to either input Devanagari or Transliteration, and then switch from one to the other.

Would be happy to know your setup, thanks in advance for the tips !

Comment: http://www.billposer.org/Software/xlit.html may be of interest.

Comment: @Thérèse thank you for the link, I have installed the program and am looking into it, do you happen to know if there are some character maps, or the like, that are available for Hindi/Sanskrit ?

Comment: Which editor do you use?  For Emacs, https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SupportHindi and http://coseruc.people.cofc.edu/unicode/ look promising, though both pages could use updating (Emacs’ support for Unicode has improved enormously).

Comment: @Thérèse Yes, the emacs program look interesting (I don't know what emacs are, so I will have to look into this more in detail...), thanks for the links! Do you happen to know what is meant by "To convert a piece of hindi text into its phonetic roman equivalent"? Would that be, for example: gītā or geetaa/giita? Regarding editors, I am using Texworks and Texmaker.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is generally about input methods (for what goes into the .tex file), and not about TeX/LaTeX itself.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first Question, I have found a program that runs on Windows (have just started playing around with it), that seems to work pretty well. You can input Devanagari and Diacritics, and it converts from one to the other in both directions.

In case this can help anyone:

http://www.kevincarmody.com/software/aksharapad.html
http://www.kevincarmody.com/software/aksharabridge.html

Regarding the 2nd question "Inputting Unicode Transliteration":

I had found some links to Ibus/M17n scripts some time ago, but it seemed complicated.

I just gave it a go, and it is actually quite easy to set up.

Here is a link to a script, which works very well (I had to tweak it a little bit to get it work on my Keyboard, but it is easy to do, and maybe for people with US keyboards, no twaeking is needed, but I can't say):

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=646207

The above link includes diacritics for Devanagari, French and German.

The following link is similar, but only Devanagari:

http://thanhsiang.org/faqing/node/109

All the necessary instructions to set this up are well explained in the above two links.

Just in case this can be useful to someone, who didn't find these directly on google ...